# Angular-UI Router -How to create dynamic routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I am new to angularjs and what I need is to build a dynamic routing mechanism in angular UI router. I have three modules like docs,tasks,dashboard and have various views within each module. Please have a look on what I have tried and suggest a solution.

app.js

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('home.documentTree', {
      url: '/documentTree',
      views: {
        'main' :{
          templateUrl: "app/documents/views/documentTree.html",
          controller: 'documentCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'documentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('home.documents', {
      url: '/documents',
      views: {
        'main' :{
          templateUrl: "app/documents/views/documentList.html",
          controller: 'documentCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'documentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    .state('home.documentDetails', {
      url: '/documentDetails',
      views: {
        'main' :{
          templateUrl: "app/documents/views/documentDetails.html",
          controller: 'documentCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'documentCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');

});
```

My html page snippet is as follows:

```
<a ui-sref="home.documentTree">Document Tree</a>
<a ui-sref="home.documents">Document Lists</a>
<a ui-sref="home.documentDetails">Document Deatils</a>
```

I have to generalize the above three routes for documents into one with dynamic parameters.

For doing this I tried the following :

```
<a ui-sref="home.:documents.:documentTree">Document Tree</a>

.state('home.:folder.:action', {
      url: 'home/:folder/:action',
      templateUrl: ['$stateParams', function ($stateParams) {
        return '/app/'+ $stateParams.folder+'/' + $stateParams.action + '.html';
      }],
      controller: 'documentCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'documentCtrl',
    })
```

But not seems to be working fine. Please suggest your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got the solution !

```
Route:
    .state('home.documents', {
          url: '/:folder/:action',
          views: {
            'main' :{
              templateUrl: function($stateParams) {
                return 'app/' + $stateParams.folder + '/views/' + $stateParams.action + '.html';
              },
              controller: 'documentCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'documentCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

Html Code :

    <a ui-sref="home.documents({folder:'documents',action:'documentTree'})">Document tree</a>
```

Just try .